# How to autoload vue3 components in combination with Laravel Mix (using the plugin "unplugin-vue-components")?

Tags: plugins, components, vuejs3, autoload, laravel-mix

I would very much like to use the vue plugin "unplugin-vue-components" to autoload vue3 components, but i unfortunately don't seem to get it to work using Laravel Mix.

Mix doesn't produce an error, but i can't autoload the components either.

*Webpack.mix.js:*

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const Components = require('unplugin-vue-components/webpack');

mix.webpackConfig({
    plugins: [
        Components({
            dirs: ['./resources/js/components']
        })
    ]
});

mix.js('resources/js/main.js', 'public/js').vue();
```

main.js:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import BalmUI from 'balm-ui'; 
import BalmUIPlus from 'balm-ui/dist/balm-ui-plus'; 

const app = createApp({});

app.use(BalmUI);
app.use(BalmUIPlus);

app.mount('#app');
```

Expected behaviour is that a vue3 component (e.g. ./resources/js/components/RecoverPassword) would be imported & initialized automatically.

Importing & initializing individual components does work.

Hope anyone can help.

Comment: did you find a way ? i am trying to do the same

Comment: Hi Kaustubh,

Unfortunately no. Components automatically link themselves when used in other components (probably by means of the "unplugin-vue-components" plugin), but they are not registered at root level.